# How to set footer at bottom of the page, (not fixed) , and remain at bottom just after loading also

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, footer

I want a footer at the bottom of the page, but its position should not be fixed. Whenever I load the page, footer comes upwards, and when data loads completely from server, footer resides at the bottom. But I want footer to be at the bottom always, but not fixed.

Here is my code:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
<div class=" row  text-center p-2" style="background-color:#e4e3dcdc; max-width: 1400px; margin: auto; bottom:0">
    <div class="col-sm-4 footer-copyright" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"> 
       1995 - {{date| date:'yyyy'}}
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <a href="#" title="Terms of Use" style="color:rgb(238, 137, 4); "> 
            Terms of Use
        </a> 
    </div>     
</div>
</footer>
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ does this solve your problem? You could also use display: grid to achieve this, but flexbox seems more suitable here to me, but that's up to you in the end

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  line-height: normal;
  height: 100%;
}


.main-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

 .page-footer {
   background: #e4e3dc;
   padding: 11px 25px;
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-row-end: 3;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/Hirengabu/k4h2pd9o/6/)